# Creating method to test Textboxes for IsDate()

Tags: vb.net

So just like the title says, all I'm trying to do is test 2 Text Boxes to check if they are valid.

Here's what I have. [I should mention that nothing happens here, it's like it tries to check if it's a date, but then goes into an infinite loop, doesn't display any error, and keeps me stuck in that text box]

```
Public Function isDate_(ByVal sender As TextBox, ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    If IsDate(CDate(sender.Text)) = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(name & " must be a valid date.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        sender.Focus()
        sender.Select(0, sender.TextLength)
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If IsDate(CDate(sender.Text)) = True Then
```

`= True` is redundant. `IsDate(CDate(x))` is redundant. A function called `isDate` shouldn’t really have side-effects.

Attempt to parse a date instead.

```
Dim d As Date

If Date.TryParse(DirectCast(sender, Control).Text, d) Then
    ' Parsing succeeded!
Else
    ' Parsing failed.
End If
```

Comment: I've been messing with this for a while, but it is still doing absolutely nothing

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the infinite loop, but your CDate is trying to convert the text to a date *before* your IsDate function can see if it's really a date or not.  Try it this way:

```
Dim testDate As Date
If Date.TryParse(sender.Text, testDate) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not interact with controls from a method that it should only return a value (That's the essence of a function), so I suggest you to use my function and adapt the other code out:

```
''' <summary>
''' Validates a Date.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Date">Indicates the Date to validate.</param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if Date is valid, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
Private Function ValidateDate(ByVal [Date] As String) As Boolean

    Return Date.TryParse([Date], New Date)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your test:

```
If IsDate(sender.Text) Then
```

`CDate(sender.Text)` will either convert the text into a date and then `IsDate` will always return `True` or `CDate` will fail with an exception, if the text is not a date. Drop `CDate`.

---

The code you are showing does not contain an infinite loop. Maybe the calling code does or an exception thrown by `CDate` somehow disturbs your program flow.